# Can't extract frames from video using C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to extract all frames from a short .mp4 video and save them as images to folder. But when I call a function cv::VideoCapture::read() it fails to extract a frame. What is the problem with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     cv::VideoCapture cap("test.mp4");

     if (!cap.isOpened()) {
         std::cout << "Cannot open the video file.\n";
         return -1;
     }

     for (int frame_count = 0; frame_count < cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); frame_count++) {
          cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_count);
          cv::Mat frame;

          if (!cap.read(frame)) {
              std::cout << "Failed to extract a frame.\n";
              return -1;
          }

          std::string image_path = "frames/" + std::to_string(frame_count) + ".jpg"; 
          cv::imwrite(image_path, frame);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output is always "Failed to extract a frame.".

Comment: have you tried it without the cap.set? let's say outside the for loop. What does the `cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` returns?

Comment: @api55 just tried it, also fails to extract frame. Without calling cap.set() and outside of the loop. cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) returns 70

Comment: Try using grab and retrieve separately (instead of read). Have you tried with another video? maybe with another codec?

Comment: What is your platfrom and OpenCV version? Did you compile it from source or download binaries?

Comment: @api55 just tried with another video and it worked! The strange thing is that it was filmed using the same phone. But the first video I tried to used with, was uploaded from iPhone to computer running PHP server script. I assume I saved it wrong somehow (in that PHP script). Because codecs for this video are: hvc1, AAC and mebx, while for the one it works with, they are AAC and H.264. My bad, thank you for help!

Comment: @Bhoke macOS 10.12.6, OpenCV 3.2.0, I followed instructions on this tutorial: https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/

Comment: probably it cannot decode it correctly and fails that is why I suggested the grab and retrieve, one fetches a frame the other one decodes it, read does both of them in one function... btw, as far as i know read will always get the next one, so you can iterate with a while cap.read is not false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the tutorial you [provided above](https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/), there is an instruction:

> Uncheck WITH_FFMPEG

ffmpeg library contains mp4 codecs, you need to check `WITH_FFMPEG` and `USE_FFMPEG` in order to read .mp4 and many other formats.

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot! I'm not experienced with CMake. If I follow the instruction again and check these flags, will it recompile the libraries, or I need to somehow delete everything related to OpenCV and follow the tutorial again? Is it ok if I just download the newest version of OpenCV and follow these instructions again?

Comment: @VolodymyrDenysov You need to recompile Opencv with WITH_FFMPEG flag checked in another directory, and you must show the path of new compiled path